# SQL Select: Get the previous Date in column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table in my SQL server with some dates. Now I would like to create a Select which gives me a column with all dates then a second column with the previous dates of the first column and a third column with the previous dates of the previous date column(c2).
For Exempel:

```
  c1(orginal)          c2(prevoius of c1)    c3(previous of c2)
2017-10-15 00:00:00   2017-04-15 00:00:00   2016-10-15 00:00:00
2017-04-15 00:00:00   2016-10-15 00:00:00   2016-04-15 00:00:00
2016-10-15 00:00:00   2016-04-15 00:00:00   2015-10-15 00:00:00
2016-04-15 00:00:00   2015-10-15 00:00:00           null
2015-10-15 00:00:00           null                  null
```

Example with colors:
[image: exemple2.0]

Is it possible to make a SELECT where the first row would be the first date from column 1, the second from column 1 and the third from column 1. The second row would be the second date from column1, the third from column 1 and the forth from column 1.

My current query

```
SELECT DISTINCT(BFSSTudStichdatum) AS C1, BFSSTudStichdatum AS C2, 
BFSSTudStichdatum AS C3  FROM BFSStudierende
ORDER BY C1 DESC
```

result:

[image]

Comment: What queries have you tried already?

Comment: do you mean previous maximum date of column1 in column2 etc. Your question states all previous dates, which means your result set will explode in size

Comment: can your data contain duplicates, if so should the duplicates be eliminated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you need to get a `distinct` list of your dates first, you will need to split your query into a common table expression and then use `lag` to get your `c2` and `c3` values:

```
declare @t table(c1 datetime);
insert into @t values ('2017-10-15 00:00:00'),('2017-04-15 00:00:00'),('2016-10-15 00:00:00'),('2016-04-15 00:00:00'),('2015-10-15 00:00:00')
                     ,('2017-10-15 00:00:00'),('2017-04-15 00:00:00'),('2016-10-15 00:00:00'),('2016-04-15 00:00:00'),('2015-10-15 00:00:00');

with c as
(
    select distinct c1
    from @t
)
select c1
      ,lag(c1, 1) over (order by c1) as c2
      ,lag(c1, 2) over (order by c1) as c3
from c
order by c1 desc;
```

Output:

```
+-------------------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+
|           c1            |           c2            |           c3            |
+-------------------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+
| 2017-10-15 00:00:00.000 | 2017-04-15 00:00:00.000 | 2016-10-15 00:00:00.000 |
| 2017-04-15 00:00:00.000 | 2016-10-15 00:00:00.000 | 2016-04-15 00:00:00.000 |
| 2016-10-15 00:00:00.000 | 2016-04-15 00:00:00.000 | 2015-10-15 00:00:00.000 |
| 2016-04-15 00:00:00.000 | 2015-10-15 00:00:00.000 | NULL                    |
| 2015-10-15 00:00:00.000 | NULL                    | NULL                    |
+-------------------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+
```

Comment: these lags dont ensure the value is less than the previous date, if the same date is repeated multiple times

Comment: @AbBennett  That is taken care of by the `select distinct` in the `cte` and the `order by` in the `lag`.  You will note that my sample data does actually include duplicates which are handled appropriately.

Comment: so if you have 8 dates, and 2 are the same your resulting dataset would be 7 rows, which is wrong. in your example you reduce 6 rows, to  5 demonstrating this

Comment: @AbBennett  If that was the case, then Gordon's answer that you have also downvoted would be correct.  Given the `distinct` included in the OP's current query however, I'm taking the extra step of assuming they want a set of unique dates.

Comment: it eliminates the duplicate dates from the final dataset though, i think that distinct is dangerous, and produces the wrong results. I am making no assumptions, to whether they are unique or should be eliminated if they are. My method is poor if you have massive amounts of rows but for small data it will be quick enough. At worst index the column

Comment: @AbBennett  It is a good thing you aren't the OP then, isn't it?

Comment: that comment makes no sense

Comment: @AbBennett  You will note this has just been accepted as the correct answer, which I think rather conclusively settles things.  It is great that you are so enthused about providing answers on here, but please only do so when you have a decent answer to give and don't get so worked up - I mean downvoting useful answers, really? - because the poster disagrees with you.

Comment: id be concerned if you eliminating rows from the final set is correct though. Can you confidently say that is what you should be doing? are you making grand assumptions here. If you had two transactions on the same day, you are now just ditching the fact that they existed as 2 and reporting it as 1

Comment: And the OP is enough satisfied with both of your answers :D

Answer (score 2):

Are you looking for `lag()`?

```
select col1,
       lag(col1, 1) over (order by col1) as col1_prev,
       lag(col1, 2) over (order by col1) as col1_prev2
from t;
```

Comment: this second lag will not ensure the 3rd date is less than the 2nd, if there are duplicate dates

Comment: I see nothing in the question that addresses that issue.  You should ask the OP (1) whether there are duplicates and (2) what to do about them.  I see no reason to complicate the question unnecessarily.

Comment: without the information you can't make the assumption there can't be duplicates

Comment: @AbBennett . . . You may not understand the question but the picture is exceedingly clear to me.  I see no ambiguity.  You should ask the OP.

Comment: how is the picture clear, if you have not asked the person or verified it with them.

Answer (score 0):

For SQL Server 2008 and later:

```
WITH DataSource AS
(
    SELECT DISTINCT *
          ,DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY c1) rowID
    FROM @t
)
SELECT DS1.[c1]
      ,DS2.[c1]
      ,DS3.[c1]
FROM DataSource DS1
LEFT JOIN DataSource DS2
    ON DS1.[rowID] = DS2.[rowID] + 1
LEFT JOIN DataSource DS3
    ON DS1.[rowID] = DS3.[rowID] + 2;
```

Answer (score 0):

For SQL Server 2008 and later:

Hope you did want an auto column generation with lagging one value behind from the past columns first value. Try the following snippet.

Created a dynamic query with respect to the number of columns in the dataset.

```
create table BFSStudierende
(
BFSSTudStichdatum  datetime
)
insert into BFSStudierende
Select getdate()
union
Select dateadd(day,1,getdate())
union
Select dateadd(day,2,getdate())
union
Select dateadd(day,3,getdate())
union
Select dateadd(day,4,getdate())

Declare @count int=(Select count(BFSSTudStichdatum ) from BFSStudierende)

Declare @query nvarchar(max)='with BFSStudierendeCte as (Select *,row_number() over(order by BFSSTudStichdatum)rn  from BFSStudierende)  Select *from BFSStudierendeCte as BFSStudierendeCte1'

Declare  @i int=2 ;
Declare  @j int ;

while(@i<=@count)
begin
Set @j=@i-1
Set @query=@query+' left outer join BFSStudierendeCte as BFSStudierendeCte'+cast(@i as varchar(5)) +' on BFSStudierendeCte1.rn+'+cast(@j as varchar(5))+'=BFSStudierendeCte'+cast(@i as varchar(5))+'.rn';
set @i+=1;
End
print @query
Execute(@query)
```

Note: Duplicate date will not be removed from the results. If you require duplicate to be removed. Please change the following line in the above snippet.

```
Declare @count int=(Select count(distinct BFSSTudStichdatum ) from BFSStudierende)

Declare @query nvarchar(max)='with BFSStudierendeCte as (Select *,row_number() over(order by BFSSTudStichdatum)rn from(Select distinct BFSSTudStichdatum from BFSStudierende)l   )  Select *from BFSStudierendeCte as BFSStudierendeCte1'
```